# ¿Como repetir una función para varias variables en python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suponiendo que tengo una función

```
def f_show(text):
  print(text)

var_1 = "algo"
var_2 = "en cada"
var_3 = "variable"
f_show(var_1)
f_show(var_2)
f_show(var_3)
```

Como llamo la función para varias variables. Sin tener que repetir f_show para cada una.

Comment: Bienvenido podrias ampliar mas le pregunta para que se entienda mas

Comment: Ya lo estás haciendo, aunque de todas formas, ese código tiene un error en la primera linea, te faltan los dos puntos al final de la cabecera de la función `def f_show(text):`...

Comment: Te refieres la forma de no tener que escribir la función tres veces en tu ejemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso de Python 2 es tan simple como pasarle las variables a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) en una lista:

```
>>> def f_show(text):
...   print(text)
>>> map(f_show, ['algo', 'en cada', 'variable'])
algo
en cada
variable
[None, None, None]
```

Lo que hace `map` es simplemente aplicar la función para cada uno de los elementos de la lista. La última línea `[None, None, None]` es el valor retornado por `map` para cada llamada a la función `f_show`, como solo estás imprimiendo el valor en realidad no nos interesa el resultado, solo nos interesa que se ejecute.

En Python 3 se complica un poco ya que `map` retorna un iterador:

```
>>> def f_show(text):
...   print(text)
... 
>>> it = map(f_show, ['algo', 'en cada', 'variable'])
>>> it
<map object at 0x7f23ee92a898>
```

Así que puedes iterar para ver los resultados:

```
>>> for x in it:
...   x
... 
algo
en cada
variable
```

Eso sigue siendo mejor que llamar a la función una por una, ¿no?

Te preguntarás para qué usar `map` si puedo iterar sobre cada variable y llamar a la función:

```
>>> for v in ['algo', 'en cada', 'variable']:
...    f_show(v)
... 
algo
en cada
variable
```

Pues, justamente lo anterior es otra forma de hacerlo. El tema es que en este caso particular solo estamos haciendo un `print`, por eso nos damos el trabajo de iterar para poder mostrarlo pero, ¿que pasaría si en vez de `print` hacemos otra cosa un poco más elaborada?:

```
def funcion_compleja(*args, **kwargs):
    # algo muy complejo por aquí
    return resultado_super_complejo
```

Pues en ese caso bastaría con convertir el resultado de`map` en una lista:

```
>>> resultados_complejos = list(map(funcion_compleja, lista_de_inputs_complejos)
```

Y esto es, en definitiva, más compacto que iterar con un `for` para llamar a la función.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no queda del todo clara tal y como la tienes formulada, de modo que voy a hacer dos suposiciones:

-Suposición 1: quieres pasar una serie de variables a una función y que esta se ejecute por cada variable.

```
def f_show(*vars):
    for i in vars:
        print(i)

var_1 = "algo"
var_2 = "en cada"
var_3 = "variable"

f_show(var_1, var_2, var_3)
```

-Suposición 2: dada una serie de variables ejecutar una o varias funciones

```
def f_show(text):
    print(text)

var_1 = "algo"
var_2 = "en cada"
var_3 = "variable"

for i in (var_1, var_2, var_3):
    f_show(i)
```

Según las necesidades será mejor una u otra.
Sin embargo si estas buscando una cantidad de variables indeterminada quizás es mejor que en lugar de variables definidas uses un diccionario, una lista, tupla, ect, puedes ver las diferencias entre ellas en la documentación oficial de python https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html